# How can I make <div> horizontally centered position using tailwindcss?

Tags: next.js, tailwind-css

```
 <div className="flex overflow-x-auto shadow-md sm:rounded-lg bg-white dark:bg-gray-800 dark:border-gray-700 w-11/12 justify-center">
        <table className="w-full text-sm text-left text-gray-500 dark:text-gray-400">
          <thead className="text-xs text-gray-700 uppercase bg-gray-50 dark:bg-gray-700 dark:text-gray-400">
            <tr>
              <th scope="col" className="px-6 py-3">
                Date
              </th>
              <th scope="col" className="px-6 py-3">
                Job Description
              </th>
              <th scope="col" className="px-6 py-3">
                Location
              </th>
              <th scope="col" className="px-6 py-3">
                Job Type / $ Rate (hourly)
              </th>
              <th scope="col" className="px-6 py-3">
                Details
              </th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr className="bg-white dark:bg-gray-800 dark:border-gray-700">
              <th
                scope="row"
                className="px-6 py-4 font-medium text-gray-900 whitespace-pre-wrap text-xs dark:text-white"
              >
                WHY NOOOO CENTERRRRRRRRRR
              </th>
              <td className="px-6 py-4">Sliver</td>
              <td className="px-6 py-4">Laptop</td>
              <td className="px-6 py-4">$2999</td>
              <td className="px-6 py-4">
                <a
                  href="#"
                  className="font-medium text-blue-600 dark:text-blue-500 hover:underline"
                >
                  Edit
                </a>
              </td>
            </tr>

            <tr className="bg-white dark:bg-gray-800">
              <th
                scope="row"
                className="px-6 py-4 font-medium text-gray-900 whitespace-nowrap dark:text-white"
              >
                Magic Mouse 2
              </th>
              <td className="px-6 py-4">Black</td>
              <td className="px-6 py-4">Accessories</td>
              <td className="px-6 py-4">$99</td>
              <td className="px-6 py-4">
                <a
                  href="#"
                  className="font-medium text-blue-600 dark:text-blue-500 hover:underline"
                >
                  Edit
                </a>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
```

I've used `flex`, `flex item-center`, and anything that says it will center the table. But, it never moves to the center position no matter what I do.

Comment: -1, tailwindcss is just CSS. If you lack CSS fundamentals, you should learn CSS. Tailwind is not a replacement for CSS, it assumes you know how to do things in CSS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because there is no parent element which is containing the `div` spanning accross the entire width of screen.

**Possible solutions**

1. Try using `mx-auto`, that will center your `table`

   Code:

   ```
   <div className="flex mx-auto ...">
       <table className="...">
   ```

---

2. If you want to use `flex` anyways, try wrapping it with a `div` and give it width of `w-screen`

   Code:

   ```
   <div class="flex w-screen justify-center">
     <div className="flex ....>
       <table> ...
     </div>
   </div>
   ```

Comment: I now have two Gods. One is Google and the other one is you sir.

Comment: Glad to hear the solutions work out for you. It takes time to understand concepts when we are new users of  `tailwind-css`, I wish you success in getting command over `tailwind-css`

Comment: I have updated my solutions to have 2 possible solutions, hope it helps !

Comment: Thank you so much. Well, I didn't like `css` so I've been using Flutter and now I am forced to learn XD

Comment: You can check out even `figma` I feel its light weight and easy to learn than `adobe xd`, anyways all the best for your journey, if you want any help in `flutter` and `tailwind-css` we are hear to help you out !

Comment: Btw, how can I make <main></main> with `width-11/12` and make them horizontally centered? I think it will be easier for me to center that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251469/discussion-between-krishna-acharya-and-chichi).